# How to make the test suite run before each build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-scripts

Currently my work flow is to run `npm test` before I run `npm build`.

Is there a way to integrate the test command into the build command so that each time I build, test is automatically run?

package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts test && react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

You can merge two steps into one using && operator. Every time you run `npm build` first it will run test cases and then build will happen